# From HWND to control

Tags: c#, winforms

Im using the FindWindow method from user32.dll to find a window and get the handle, but is it possible to get the form control from the handle? and the use it like an ordinary form? Example:

```
int myhwnd = FindWindow(null, "MyWindow");
form myform = SomeMagic.GetFormFromHandle(myhwnd);
myform.Visible = false;
```

or do I have to continue to use the methods in user32.dll to send a message to the window?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If it's a managed window (you've created it with System.Windows.Forms, and it has inherited from System.Windows.Forms.Control) you can get a reference to the Control object with

```
Control.FromHandle(myIntPtr);
```

Then you just get the parent of the control until you get the form.

If not, you can't get a Control object, what you can do though is to is to create a NativeWindow, and assign the IntPtr handle to the object with the AssignHandle. That will at least give you some access to the WndProc, and similar, but that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [Control.FromHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle.aspx)? Forms are (inherit from) Controls. If you hit a nested control, you'll have to search up through its parents until you hit your Form.

This assumes there actually is a `Form` somewhere, and you've just used the user32 methods to locate its `HWND`.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to wrap a Form class around Win32 window handle. There is no full fledged implementation provided by Microsoft. So, you have to use Native functions only to communicate with a given handle.

Answer (score 1):

If the window belongs to your application you can use [Control.FromHandle Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle.aspx). Otherwise you will have to continue using win api. For example to hide the window you need to call [ShowWindow Function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28VS.85%29.aspx)