# How to get Control coordinates on mouse Clicked ? C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get control coordinates on mouse Clicked. Let's say after running my app user click on Visual Studio File Menu. So, I want to get File Menu control Coordinates. This is the code I have tried. I am not successful getting it.
Note: This is windform application.

```
if (ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))
{
    // MessageBox.Show("Width:" + ClientRectangle.Width.ToString() + "--- Height: " + ClientRectangle.Height.ToString() + "---" + "X:" + ClientRectangle.X.ToString() + "--- Y: " + ClientRectangle.Y.ToString());
    Point location = button1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
    MessageBox.Show(location.X.ToString()+"---------"+location.Y.ToString()+"---------"+ location+ClientRectangle.Width.ToString()+"---------"+ClientRectangle.Height.ToString());
    // Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    int with = ClientRectangle.Width;
    int height = ClientRectangle.Height;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)with, (int)height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    // g.CopyFromScreen(ClientRectangle.Left, ClientRectangle.Top, 50,50, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    g.CopyFromScreen(location.X, location.Y, 0, 0, new Size(ClientRectangle.Width-30, ClientRectangle.Height-36));
    bmp.Save(@"capture.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
}
```

Any Suggestion code will be much appreciated.

Comment: In web applications when you want to get the cursor position inside a div or something, you calculate the cursor x and y positions, and subtract the offset x and y of the div from the respective positions. I think you could do something like that. Your offset would be the control's position. Not sure about the menus, but you can have an idea.

Comment: What type of application? WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET (MVC/WebForms)?

Comment: *"control coordinates on mouse Clicked"* - erm, what? How do you know what that would be a `Control`? And if you get that what was clicked, what are you going to do with it?

Comment: @DHansen this is windform application.

Comment: @Sinatr. Whenever Mouse clicked on something. I will try to get controls coordinates. After getting controls coordinates, I will capture a screenshot of that particular control and save it. This app basically belongs to training app. Which is used to train new users of previous steps.

Comment: How does screenshot of clicked control helps in training? With your approach it very much depends what is the application what you are clicking. For most you can obtain HWND and if it is a winforms - [get a `Control` from it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3996547/1997232). But e.g. WPF application required special approach, as their controls doesn't have handles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201286/get-cursor-position-with-respect-to-the-control-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:
    [Getting mouse position in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp)

```
?
```

Thanks

Comment: there is a problem with this solution. This solution only gives cursor points which is the sub part of control and I need to get the whole control.

Comment: Wow. Sorry about that. I think you have two options:Control Position or Mouse Hook. Link 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578654/which-control-has-been-clicked  or Link 2: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C